# How to count Push notification message badge on android app icon in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, badge

I have run my Project in Mi device. In Mi device Push notification Badge Count and display on app icon but another device sumsung, lenovo not display push notification Badge on app icon. first,How to count Push notification message in background after how to count this message and display it app icon.

FirebaseMessaging.java

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = FirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            int badge = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badge);
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            // String date = data.getString("date1");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to count the push notification using your own logic, something like increasing the value in shared preference etc.

Comment: how to sent push notification message count and display badge in sumsung device

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-badges.html

Comment: this link static display badge count but i need to background count badge on android app.

Comment: background count badge means what ?

Comment: push notification badge

Answer (score 2):

**You can User below code for count at on app icon**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Read previous value. If not found, use 0 as default value.
    int count = sharedPreferences.getInt("noticount", 0);

    // because you need to show the badge again, it means you need
    // to increment the count
    count = count + 1;

    // Then apply it
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getBaseContext(), count);

    // After that, you need to save the value again for another badge count
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("your_key", count);
    editor.commit();
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), count);
```

Comment: you saved my day brother. can you confirm is it working in stock OS devices as well or only on limited devices?